# Asp .net core 3.1 JWT and SignalR authentication login part

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, signalr

I'm new with **SignalR** and  I am using both **ASPNET Core 3.1** in server and client(console app).

I tried to make login part which provides to user his token, since token has short lifespan, it needs to be regenerated.

I followed this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1 but I missed part where server gives client his new token.

Do I need to make Http call to server to get token and/or renew it or SignalR it somehow manages to get token and renew it, please explain me this.

Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution on how to refresh the token in signalr?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to Authenticate first, and then, before your token expired, you should refresh the token with another request.

After you get the new token from your server, use should use it for every new **SignalR** connection that you will do.

See @JasonWatmore [relative article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/25/aspnet-core-3-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens) for more info.

Comment: that means before i make signalr connection i first need http request to server to get token, right?

Comment: but how do I replace existing token in signalR hub if its already active, do I need to close and open again with new token?

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe that because you have already initialized the connection with a valid token, If your connection is not dropped you don't need to change your token. 

But If connection drop and recreated then use your new token.

Comment: well I'd like to keep same connection id for whole application lifetime and overwrite once token is expired with new one. But before new hub connection, connection is build and then connected, in that case single application would need to open and close many hub connections, which would create additional headache

Comment: Ι would suggest you not to based on Signalr's connection Id. 

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: conenction id is used as token to get new one, since connection id is one per conenction it perfectly fits as refresh token

Comment: Also thanks for article, but problem is that it shows for web based application, I need same thing on console application(client)